# Does the Client Required OpenCv Installation on their machine to run the C++ DLL ( used Opencv Libraries )?

Tags: c++, opencv, dll

How to make a DLL where Declaration and implementation Part separately.

Explanation:

In DLL

I have installed Opencv in my machine and i need to to create a DLL where the Client can access my DLL on their fresh machine ( Without OpenCV Installation). how to build such DLL

I created dll but when i ran on the another Machine it asks for Opencv Header Files ?? how to fix this ??

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, but if you link your C++ application to 3rd party libraries, you will need to either distribute those libraries (as a DLL) or statically link to the libraries.

Comment: Let me explain you in detail, i have build the c++ DLL which i used Opencv Libraries , but when i test the DLL on another with TestApplication - it asking for Opencv Header files like error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv/cv.h': No such file or directory, error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp'

Comment: If TestApplication is in source code and needs compiled on the client you will need to distribute the header files along with your dll. If TestApplication is a compiled application you will just need the dlls.

Comment: @drescherjm To Compile the TestApplication, Do we need to give the Opencv Header files also ?

Comment: Yes you will need to distribute the headers in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use DLLs the header files for those DLLs also need to be included. You will provide headers to your client.

Comment: my question is Does the Client Required OpenCv Installation on their machine to run the C++ DLL ( used Opencv Libraries )?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking to do is compile OpenCV and your program for static linking. Basically what this does is that instead of linking your newly compiled DLL to the OpenCV DLLs you link against .obj files for the OpenCV library. The problem with this method is that you will have to compile it separately for each platform you want to support. Some example directions to get you started can be found [here](http://www.shiffman.net/2011/01/23/how-to-build-opencv-static-libraries-mac-os-x/). It is for Mac, but it walks through the basic process which will be somewhat similar for any other platform.

Answer (score 1):

For running OpenCV included app(exe) in another system(without installed openCV),
Just copy the 'dll' files(only dlls)from 'C:\OpenCV2.1\bin' or the bin folder in the opencv installed directory and paste them with your exe directory.