# How to create a desktop icon on User's computer to run C++ program which contains Gtkmm and Opencv libraries?

Tags: c++, opencv, gtkmm, software-distribution, gtkmm3

I'm using Windows 10 OS and Code::blocks IDE.
I want to provide an executable of my 'cpp' program to user, by double clicking on it the program should run. I got .exe file from code::blocks project. When I run .exe on User's pc it shows following error libgtkmm-3.0-1.dll and libopencv_world320.dll are missing.
[image] [image]

When I run .exe on My PC it runs perfectly fine, the same .exe doesn't run on user's computer. The 'cpp' program uses 'gtkmm' for GUI and 'opencv' to capture frames from camera. How do I solve my 'dll' files not found error? What all will I need in order to launch a program using .exe on User's computer?

Comment: Related [Does the Client Required OpenCv Installation on their machine to run the C++ DLL  used Opencv Libraries ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16140829/205233)

Answer (score 0):

I copied all dll files of both Gtkmm and Opencv into folder where '.exe' file is present on user's computer. It worked perfectly fine. One can find .dll files in bin folders of respective libraries.

Comment: Please consider accepting your own answer if it solved your issue. This could help future users. Thanks!